# Resize axis lenght

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Good evening,
I'm plotting my DF on this figure with the following code:

```
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

#fig(finestra) creation and subplot(threedee) creation#
finestra = plt.figure(figsize = (10,20))
threedee = finestra.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection = '3d')

#meshgrid#
x,y = np.meshgrid(df_giornaliero_p.columns, df_giornaliero_p.index)
z = df_giornaliero_p.values

#projection, grid's step setting to 1, axis labels, colorbar e show#
grafico = threedee.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, linewidth=0, cmap=cm.coolwarm, antialiased=0)

threedee.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
threedee.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
threedee.zaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

threedee.set_xlabel('COLONNE')
threedee.set_ylabel('ESTRAZIONI')
threedee.set_zlabel('VALORI')

finestra.colorbar(grafico, shrink=1, aspect=90)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Plotted Graphic]

---

Now, as you all can see, my Y and Z ticks values overlaps, I was wandering if there's a way to extend Y and Z axes in order to get a **wider** graph and have a clear view of all datas that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Please, note that:

-Thicks count must be as setted(x=20, y=288, z=90)

-What's to be canged is **axis lenght** or the **step** between each tick.

-I really don't care about the box shape the graph actually have.

**Thank you all in advance.**

Comment: My first idea was to use `change_aspect()` on the 3daxis object. But this is apparently not implemented, at least not in matplotlib 3.1.3. So, you could somewhat work around it by changing the figuresize, but this is not really satisfying.

Comment: Actually, I already tried ```axis.change_aspect()```and got exactly the errorcode you had ```'Axes3DSubplot' object has no attribute 'change_aspect'.``` So I would just like to understand if I'm looking for an ***unexisting something*** or if ***there's a way***.

Comment: Sorry, i mistyped. The function that came to mind was `set_aspect`. This throws a `NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes`

Answer (score 0):

Good Evening!

Can you not do it by playing around with the `figsize`?

Assuming that `df_giornaliero_p` is set like this:

`df_giornaliero_p = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((20,20)))*100`

and the figsize is increased:

```
finestra = plt.figure(figsize = (20,60))
```

You can also adjust the text size, before `plt.show()`:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=25)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=25)
ax.tick_params(axis='z', labelsize=20)
```

I get

[image]

Comment: This will just strech the plot, and by the way, since figsize uses 2d params it's just impossible to increase the image depth on a 2d screen. Thanks anyway, guess I'll just give up on that.